# Is it possible to Query non nullable fields in Graphql without referencing it's type

Tags: python, graphql, aws-appsync

New to Graphql. I've been searching for whether this is possible or not for hours. Take the code below for example...

```
type Character {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    episodes: [Episodes!]!
}

type Episodes {
    episode_number: Int
    title: String
    season: Int
}
```

Is it possible to Query `episode_number` to find the Character `name` that was in that episode?

Comment: depends on query/resolver implementation, not only querying problem ... define reverse relation (types and supporting DB), see book/author examples

Comment: Thank you! I crafted my solution.